# Finding out the inverse of elements

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

Let $X=\lbrace 0,1,2,3,...,99 \rbrace$ For $a,b$ in $X$ we define $a*b$ to be the remainder obtained by dividing the product $ab$ by $100$. For example $9*18=62$ and $7*5=35$. Let $x$ be an element in $X$. An element $y$ in $X$ is called the inverse of $x$ if $x*y=1$ The question is to find out which of the elements $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ have inverses and also find out their inverses.

We have to find out the number which on multiplication with the given number results in $01$ to be the last two digits.I understand that inverse $1,2,5$ doesn't exist but couldn't figure out others. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the inverse of $1$ doesn't exist? And what about inverses of multiples of $2$ or $5$?

Comment: What can you say if the element $x$ is relatively prime to 100 (i.e., if $\gcd(x,100)=1$)?

Comment: @ArnaudD. i thought that $1$ multiplied by any other number results in the number itself.Since no number in set ends with $01$ so its inverse is not possible

Comment: @Pink What is $1*1$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ah the numbers can be same.So $2,5$ don't have inverses.how to check others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You're looking for numbers that are relatively prime to $100$ that satisfy the equation 
$$ax \equiv 1 \space\ (\text{mod} \space\ 100)$$
where $a = \left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\right\}$ per your question. I will correct your mistake with the element $a=1$, note that:
$$(1)(x) \equiv 1 \space\ (\text{mod} \space\ 100)$$
is satisfied when $x=1$, so that the inverse of $1$ is itself, in other words, $a = 1 = a^{-1}$. Then, ask yourself why there would not be an $x$ that satisfies 
$$2x \equiv 1 \space\ (\text{mod} \space\ 100).$$
Think of plugging in values of $x$, every product $2x$ would be...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yes that's way $2$,$4$,$6$, and $5$ don't possess inverses.But what about $3$ and $7$

Comment: Indeed! For $3$ and $7$ they do possess inverses modulo $100$. The way I go about thinking about it is trying to find a multiple of $3$ that would satisify $3x - 100y = 1$, first I might think of $x=33$ and $y=1$, but that wouldn't work. Then, I move onto $y=2$, and $x=67$ since this product of $3$ and $67$ will get me the closest to $200$, and surely $3(67) = 201$, so that,
$$3(67) \equiv 1 \space\ (\text{mod} \space\ 100)$$,
so that the inverse of $3$ is $67$ modulo $100$.

Comment: It really boils down to the Euclidean Algorithm, I tend to go about it in a more naive way when dealing with congruencies though truth be told.

Comment: And the inverse of 7 is 43 modulo 100

Comment: Yes since $7(43) = 301 \equiv 1 \space\ (\text{mod} \space\ 100)$.